# The quotient of the constant sheaf by the structure sheaf is flasque.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be an integral scheme of finite type over $k$ with $\dim(X)=1$. Let $\mathcal{K}_{X}$ be the constant sheaf on $X$ with value $K(X)$, where $K(X)$ is the function field of $X$.

I want to show that the quotient sheaf $\mathcal{G}:=\mathcal{K}_{X}/\mathcal{O}_{X}$ is flasque.

Since $X$ is integral (and thus irreducible) we clearly see that the constant sheaf itself $\mathcal{K}_{X}$ is flasque. (don't know if this fact will be useful).

We thus want to show that for every open $V\subset U\subset X$ the restriction map $r:\mathcal{G}(U)\rightarrow\mathcal{G}(V)$ is surjective.

**Note** that the quotient sheaf is defined as the sheafification of the quotient presheaf mapping an open $U\mapsto \mathcal{K}_{X}(U)/\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$.

**Added Approach:** What I tried to show is that $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ is flasque, since then I could use the exact sequence $0\to\mathcal{O}_{X}\to\mathcal{K}_{X}\to\mathcal{K}_{X}/\mathcal{O}_{X}\to 0$ and the fact that $\mathcal{K}_{X}$ is flasque to conclude that $\mathcal{K}_{X}/\mathcal{O}_{X}$ is also flasque. (see comments for a counter example).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Right now this reads as a [no-clue question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions). What have you tried? (There is only one reasonable approach.)

Comment: @KReiser Sorry, you are right. I added my approach. I will keep this in mind when I post a question in the future.

Comment: Note: $\mathcal{O}_X$ is definitely not always flasque, even when $X$ is affine. For example, the structure sheaf of $X = \mathbb{A}^1 = \operatorname{Spec}(k[x])$ is not flasque because the restriction map from global sections to sections over the principal open set $D(x)$ is the localization map $k[x] \to k[x]_x$, which is injective but not an isomorphism.

Comment: Also, if you are asking this for Hartshorne exercise III.2.2 (just a guess but I don't often see this quotient sheaf appearing), notice that if $\mathcal{O}_X$ was indeed flasuqe you wouldn't need the sequence, as cohomology for flasque sheaves is already trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking sections on any open subset $U\subset X$ and using the fact that flasque sheaves have no higher cohomology we get a long exact sequence $$0\to \mathcal{O}_X(U)\to \mathcal{K}_X(U)\to (\mathcal{K}_X/\mathcal{O}_X)(U) \to H^1(\mathcal{O}_X,U) \to 0.$$

Using the restriction maps, we have the following diagram for each pair $V\subset U\subset X$ (it suffices to consider $V\subsetneq U$ since the restriction map $res_{U,U}=id$ is always surjective):

$$
    \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
    \newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
    \newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
    \begin{array}{c}
0 & \ra{} & \mathcal{O}_X(U) & \ra{} & \mathcal{K}_X(U) & \ra{} & (\mathcal{K}_X/\mathcal{O}_X)(U) & \ra{} & H^1(\mathcal{O}_X,U) & \ra{} & 0 \\
\da{} & & \da{res_{U,V}} & & \da{res_{U,V}} & & \da{res_{U,V}} & & \da{res^1_{U,V}} & & \da{} \\
0 & \ras{} & \mathcal{O}_X(V) & \ras{} & \mathcal{K}_X(V) & \ras{} & (\mathcal{K}_X/\mathcal{O}_X)(V) & \ras{} & H^1(\mathcal{O}_X,V) & \ras{} & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

and we would love to use this to conclude that the restriction map on $\mathcal{K}_X/\mathcal{O}_X$ is surjective using one of the weaker versions of the [Five lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma#Statements). But we need more information before we can apply that lemma. We have that the restriction map $res_{U,V}:\mathcal{K}_X(U)\to\mathcal{K}_X(V)$ is surjective by definition of a flasque sheaf, and the final right-hand map $0\to 0$ is injective, but we need to show that our map $res_{U,V}^1:H^1(\mathcal{O}_X,U)\to H^1(\mathcal{O}_X,V)$ is surjective in order to use the lemma and be done.

This is where the assumptions that $X$ is an integral curve comes in. In an integral curve, every proper open subset $U\subsetneq X$ is affine, so $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X,V)=0$. So $res_{U,V}^1:H^1(\mathcal{O}_X,U)\to H^1(\mathcal{O}_X,V)=0$ is the zero map to the zero module, which is surjective. So we're done.

Comment: Why don't we have a map $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X,U)\to H^1(\mathcal{O}_X,V)$ ? The natural transformation $res_{U,V}$ should give rise to a natural transformation between $H^1$, do I miss something ?

Comment: I agree there should be a natural map there, but it is still important to know $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X, V) = 0$ to conclude that this map is $0$.

Comment: @Roland that sounds reasonable but I'm afraid it's late and I'm missing a detail or two. Can you remind me why $res_{U,V}$ should do such a thing?

Comment: If you have a natural map between functors $\varphi:F\to G$, you have a natural map between their derived functors $R^1F\to R^1G$. Now $res_{U,V}$ is such a natural map between $H^0(U,.)\to H^0(V,.)$ and the derived functor of $H^0(U,.)$ is indeed $H^i(U,.)$ (this part is not totally obvious, but true for open subsets).

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you for the reminder. I will update the post.

Comment: @Roland The definition of sheaf cohomology that I learned is that $H^i(U, {-})$ is the $i$th right derived functor of $H^0(U, {-})$ (for $U$ an open subset of $X$), making the "not totally obvious" claim true by definition. Am I missing a subtlety?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Let $Z\subset X$ is any subset and $i:Z\to X$ the inclusion. Given a sheaf $F$ on $X$, you can define $F|_Z=i^{-1}F$. You can also define $H^0(Z,F)=H^0(Z,F|_Z)$. Here you have a good definition of the sections of $F$ above any subset. But now what is $H^i(Z,F)$ ? This is NOT the derived functor of $H^0(Z,.)$ (this notion is not interesting), in fact $H^i(Z,F)=H^i(Z,F|_Z)$ (and you should always write the latter, never write the former to avoid confusion). But for open subset, they both coincide.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, I think I understood this well enough and just had different definitions than the ones you're using (tbh yours seem better). It is clear to me that $H^i(Z,{-})$ is not the $i$th right derived functor of $H^0(Z,{-})$ in general, but my definitions were set up so that $H^i(U,{-})$ is canonically identified with the $i$th right derived functor of $H^0(U,{-})$ when $U$ is open.